# C# run time consuming method on button click without keeping the button pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I do have experience with software developping in Python (GUI platform PyQt) and I am learing software development in C#. I wanted to know how can I run a thread/task in C# that uses UI objects but keeping the UI "alive" and not keeping the button pressed. I did used "Invoke" method to share UI objects with thread/task and did not call any join method, but still button remain pressed during thread execution. Is there any way to run this method in background, but keeping the GUI responsive?

Thanks in advance!

---

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(new Action(this.Iterate_balance));

}

private async void Iterate_balance()
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        // the rest of code
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change `async void` to `async Task` and then just `await Iterate_balance();`

Comment: @MikeHjortChristensen well I did modify the code like: `private async void Calculate_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await  this.Iterate_balance();

        }` and the method to run:
`private async Task Iterate_balance()
{
    bool iteration_successful = false;
    while (condition)
    {
        //iteration
    }
}`

but the button still remain pressed during execution and UI does not respond. In first look it looks like I am not missing something, but probably I am. Any idea where I am wrong? Thanks

Comment: ofcuase it will you are `await`ing it. If you don't want to block simply do `Iterate_balance();` and then you don't need to have the `async` on your button. Unless you are awaiting other code.

Comment: I did it and I got the same results. I think this is because the method Iterate_balance() read and writes some UI objects and this is done automatically becaouse of self-synchronisation. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're probably right. perhaps you should look into [Databinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-wpf) for updating your XAML :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY THIS:**

1.Add following using:    `using System.ComponentModel;`

2.Declare [background worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
```

3.Register events:

```
worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

4.Implement two methods:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   // run all background tasks here
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, 
                                       RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  //update ui once worker complete his work
}
```

5.Run worker async whenever your need.

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Also if you want to report process progress you should subscribe to ProgressChanged event and use  ReportProgress(Int32) in DoWork method to raise an event. Also set following: worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

Hope this help.

Comment: Using this method, releases the button and the UI becomes active (which is a part of the problem), but the program raises an exception for the using UI objects in another thread. Then when I tried to use Dispatch the button remained pressed and UI not responsive.

Comment: First, Thanks for the help. The way that it worked is this:
1. I created some fields to save the UI object  values (this way I do not have to access UI object in another thread) 2. Then I splitted the method in too "smaller" methods, where one works with UI objects (passes those values to class fields) and the other method does iterations stuff using fields values. 3. After `worker` has completed, passes founded values to some other fields in the class 4. Finally RunWorkerCompleted  event updates the GUI with founded values using class fields.

Comment: The problem was linked with the "structure" of the method that I have builded, so almost every "standard" mode would not make it work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

use async/await pattern properly and you won't need Dispatcher at all:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Iterate_balance();    
}

private async Task Iterate_balance()
{
    button.Content = "Click to stop";

    // some long async operation
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));

    button.Content = "Click to run";
}
```

Comment: Also looking since he is new to it you should advise him to look up on databinding and MVVM :-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I modify the code like the description, but the button still remain pressed. Probably I am missing something due to the fact that I am new to C#:

 private async Task Iterate_balance()
 {
  bool iteration_successful = false; 
  // the rest of code
 }

 private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
  await Iterate_balance();

 }

Comment: is "the rest of code" asynchronous? if it is running on main thread, then UI will be blocked

Comment: Well I supposed it was automatically asynchronous, but after reading the question i understand that I'm wrong. No, I have not declared that part of code like asynchronous. "the rest of code" is a while loop that takes some time to execute. Should I declare the while loop in another method and after that run the method using await?

Comment: @JonadriBundo, `await` needs a Task to wait for completion. you probably need smth like: `await Task.Run(LongOperation);` where LongOperation contain time-consuming code: `private void LongOperation() { while ... }`. this way long operation is performed in a separate thread

Comment: Negative again, I tried that, but i could not run because of error "CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Task.Run(Action)' and 'Task.Run(Func<Task>)' ". then after running the method inside Task.Run() with a lambda expression/new Action I got an runtime exception telling me that can not use objects because are in another thread (the reason why I was using Invoke)